# Problem with loop-generated pkgkeys containing a space

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'm trying to use `\pgfkeys` in the following setting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    m1 color/.initial=red,
    m2 color/.initial=green,
    m3 color/.initial=blue,
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 3} {%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/m\i color/.get=\c}
    \node at (0, \i) [color=\c] {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `\c '.
```

If I change the code to not use `\i` to select the key, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    m1 color/.initial=red,
    m2 color/.initial=green,
    m3 color/.initial=blue,
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 3} {%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/m1 color/.get=\c}
    \node at (0, \i) [color=\c] {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

then it compiles, but now I can't iterate over the keys.

I also noticed that *this* actually works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    color1/.initial=red,
    color2/.initial=green,
    color3/.initial=blue,
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 3} {%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/color\i/.get=\c}
    \node at (0, \i) [color=\c] {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So what's the problem with the first example?

Just for curiosity, I tried changing `m1 color` to `m1_color`, and *now* it works. Hence, it appears to have something to do with the spaces. But what?

Comment: `pgfkeys` is loaded implicitly by `tikz` package anyway so you don't need to include it externally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros remove any spaces behind them, so `m\i color` will be expanded to `m1color` not `m1 color`, etc. You need to add an explict space: `m\i\space color`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    m1 color/.initial=red,
    m2 color/.initial=green,
    m3 color/.initial=blue,
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 3} {%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/m\i\space color/.get=\c}
    \node at (0, \i) [color=\c] {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also note that using a macro for a key value is not always supported. In the case of `color` it is, but for other keys you might want to expand it first by adding `/.expand once` to the key, like `color/.expand once=\c`.

Comment: I suspected that that was the problem, but I wasn't aware of the `\space` command (I  tried using `m\i\ color` but that didn't work).

Comment: @gablin: The space must be expandable. `\ ` adds a typesetable space which isn't. `\space` on the other site simply expands to ` `.

Answer (score 5):

It compiles without error if you change

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/m\i color/.get=\c}
```

to

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/m\i\space color/.get=\c}
```

I can't promise it gets the result you intend though.....